# What's up with Luthor's Lair in Superman?

Tags: dc, superman

Lex Luthor's lair in [Superman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078346/combined) appears to be a partially submerged, palatial train station:

[image]

No explanation of how this place came to be, how Lex came into possession of it, or how it became partially filled with water is present in the movie. Does anyone have any secondary sources for what's going on?

Comment: I read "hair" at first glance..and thought...what hair?

Comment: He's rich... so, he does what he wants?

Comment: The style is identical to that of Grand Central terminal in New York City.  In fact, when the cop is chasing Otis down a tunnel, the train that comes through even has the "NH" logo of the New York-New Haven line locomotives.  The line Lex says - "How many women do you know who have a Park Avenue address like this one?" and her response of "Park Avenue?  Two hundred feet BELOW?".

It's New York rename Metropolis (since they even included the World Trade Center in the flying scenes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He says it in the movie that he took over an abandoned railroad station and made it his own.

Even in NYC today (which is what Metropolis in the movie was based off of) there are many abandoned stations that go unused and people live in them.
]

---

To quote Lex from the movie:

> LUTHOR
>   When I was a mere prodigy, Miss Teschmacher, having 
>   passed through vandalism with flying  colours at the age 
>   of six, my father said to me: "Son, stocks will rise and fall. . . .
>                                               **(gesturing around him)**
>   *Utilities and transportation systems may even collapse*, and 
>   people are no damn good - but they'll always need land, and 
>   for that they'll pay, through the nose. Remember that," my 
>   father said. "Land."

Emphasis mine. Implying that he took over the area from a transportation system that "collapsed"

[source](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/superman_I_shoot.txt)

Comment: Lex's digs are fancier than the place the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles call home. He must live uptown.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandoned_railway_station#Cultural_significance) for some relevant data :)  - This significant quote: "Rather they were constructed to allow for future expansion, but never actually used."  Also, here's a list for [NYC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_New_York_City_Subway_stations)

Comment: @MajorStackings - uptown Manhattan is note exactly the best part of town. Harlem and all. Fancy is Midtown.

Comment: @DVK Uptown. Downtown. It's all the big apple to me.

Comment: If you can get the actual quote from the movie, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens I added a quote.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that Lex has simply identified an unused space and is living in it, rent free and presumably stealing power and cable-feeds from the city above him.

The [original shooting script](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_I_shoot.txt) gives us a bunch more info, along with a description of his *heated swimming pool* (which I suspect is the water you're referring to).

> **LEX LUTHOR AND LAIR**
>
> LEX LUTHOR sits behind a massive desk in his palatial underground lair, now seen for the first time as CAMERA PANS: At first glance - breathtaking, with its multi-leveled areas, only some of which are immediately visible. The entire wall behind him which rises to a high ceiling is completely covered with full bookcases bulging with periodicals, papers, etc. Another separate area has a complicated laboratory with viewing theater, banks of electronic gadgets which have been connected to underground electrical lines exposed in portions of the rock-faced walls. In the same manner we will discover exposed heating ducts and water mains. One higher level near the ceiling is completely blocked from view. Off to another  side - a large and colourful aviary,  stocked with live birds of prey: eagles, falcons, hawks, etc. The walls and ceilings, as we will discover, are almost all canvas on which projections can and will be made, different ones servicing different specific parts of the lair.
>
> One other aspect of this underground kingdom will soon become apparent: whether through the architecture which strangely resembles that of Metropolis Station, or the row of bookcases which curiously look like old ticket windows, or the odd, faded track marker which signals the way off into one or another of the hidden corridors of the lair - **it is clear we are in an abandoned railroad station, drastically remodeled, but nonetheless a fact.**

and

> The highest level of the underground complex is an improvised swimming pool area. The domed ceiling hangs low over what once was a massive staircase down into the station and  now serves as the entrance steps to the pool. A projection of an idyllic Caribbean island setting and seascene shimmers against one wall. LUTHOR sits in the shallow end of the pool in a roped-off, bubbling Jacuzzi bath section. EVE, looking fetching in a bikini, lies on a mat nearby, black goggles over her eyes, absorbing rays from a sunlamp. OTIS sits in an armchair, watches the NEWSCASTER on a television in front of him.

Answer (score 0):

The entrance to the lair appears to be in a non-subway tunnel.  (Seems pretty clear that is not a subway that runs down the guy chasing Lex's assistant)  Assuming some consistency with reality in the movie (ha!) then the options in Manhattan would be Grand Central Terminal (Grand Central Station is actually the post office next door), or Penn Station.

All the abandoned stations in NYC are pretty ugly and in usually poor state.

This looks like a scaled down version of Grand Central, and probably was intended as such.